# Transform row data into column by certain row name in R

Tags: r, merge, transformation, transpose

Hey so I'm pretty new to R and only familiar with some functions.I have a row data of around 2,000,000 rows.

Raw data is like this, an item has four kinds of tariff (AHS, BND, MFN, PRF). Some data have PRF and some don't. The goal is to transform each item's tariff into a column by the type of tariff.

```
AHS      3.00 
BND      3.80
MFN      4.00
PRF      2.00
AHS      4.00
BND      3.80
MFN      4.00
```

How to transform the raw data into like this:

```
AHS   BND   MFN   PRF
3.00  3.80  4.00  2.00
4.00  3.80  4.00  NA
```

I tried rbind, for those don't have PRF, R will assign the AHS to PRF.

Can anyone tell me how to do this transformation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there any other "rules" to the problem? Are the data always in the same order (AHS, BND, MFN or AHS, BND, MFN, PRF)?

Comment: Yes, it's in that order

Comment: Cool. Then I would recommend the "data.table" approach I mentioned, making sure to also use `cummax`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I just find that the data is not in that order. All data has MFN, how can I re-order the column to make MFN at the front of each item? Thanks. It seems setorder() can't order by specific value

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of where the problem might occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `grp` variable which is 1 for the first group, 2 for the second, etc.  Then use `tapply`

```
grp <- cumsum(DF$V1 == "AHS")
tapply(DF$V2, list(grp, DF$V1), sum)
```

giving:

```
  AHS BND MFN PRF
1   3 3.8   4   2
2   4 3.8   4  NA
```

We used this as the data:

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = c("AHS", "BND", "MFN", "PRF", "AHS", "BND", "MFN"), 
                 V2 = c(3, 3.8, 4, 2, 4, 3.8, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ave` in base R or a comparable approach in a package to create the "id" variable. Since some "PRF" values are missing, you probably also need to use `cummax` during the id creation stage.

Here are some alternatives, all using @G.Grothendieck's sample data. My vote would go for the "data.table" approach.

```
DF <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("AHS", "BND", "MFN", "PRF", "AHS", "BND", "MFN"), 
  V2 = c(3, 3.8, 4, 2, 4, 3.8, 4), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Base R: `reshape`

Notorious for its syntax... and probably not recommended for working with 2M rows....

```
reshape(within(DF, {
  id <- cummax(ave(V1, V1, FUN = seq_along))
}), direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "V1")
```

#### Base R: `xtabs`

Easier to remember syntax, but less flexible. Also, returns a `matrix`, so you'll need to use `as.data.frame.matrix` if you want to get a `data.frame`. Fills missing values with "0", which may not be desirable.

```
xtabs(V2 ~ id + V1, within(DF, {
  id <- cummax(ave(V1, V1, FUN = seq_along))
}))
```

#### "data.table"

Fast. Predictable behavior from `dcast.data.table` following behavior long established by `dcast` from "reshape2".

```
library(data.table)
dcast.data.table(
  as.data.table(DF)[, id := sequence(.N), by = V1][, id := cummax(id)], 
                 id ~ V1, value.var = "V2")
#    id AHS BND MFN PRF
# 1:  1   3 3.8   4   2
# 2:  2   4 3.8   4  NA
```

Comment: +1 for *so expect headaches for syntax and functions changing and your old code breaking every time you update your packages.*  This is why I stick mostly with base R.  All the `*yr` packages are getting all tangled up. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven, I saw an XKCD knockoff recently where the captions of the original were replaced with something on the same topic of package updates--can't remember where though. I would say that the `dcast` behavior is pretty well-established now, but there are some differences between the "reshape2" version and the "data.table" version.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried data.table method. It turns out like this.... The one that has value is 1, those don't have value 0. It seems like a boolean value.
#    id AHS BND MFN PRF
# 1:  1   1   1   1   1
# 2:  1   1   1   1   0

Comment: @StatCC, Your data might not be as tidy as you expect and some groups may have duplicated values. This leads to the default aggregation being `length`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto What do you mean by duplicated values? It did return "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'"